# Trouble playing video in html

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I have an html file that uses JavaScript to display a clock. I want to modify this html to also play a looped video below the clock. However, the video does not display if I have the clock active; it works when I deactivate the clock (comment out the clock divs). Does anyone know how I can fix this? Sorry for the tangled mess of CSS/HTML/JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>

<title>Javascript Clock</title><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();

var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();

var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var year = today.getFullYear();

var hsec=Math.floor(today.getMilliseconds());
// add a zero in front of numbers<10

document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+checkTime(m)+":"+checkTime(s)+":"+checkHTime(hsec);
document.getElementById('cal').innerHTML=checkTime(month)+"/"+checkTime(day)+"/"+year;
setTimeout('startTime()',10);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
function checkHTime(i)
{
if (i<100)
  {
  if (i<10)
    {
    i="0" + i;
    }

  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}

</script></head>
<body onload="startTime()" bgcolor="black">

<center><br><br><br><img style="width: 776px; height: 133px;" alt="ad" src="ad-logo-pms2945%    20png.png"><br><br>
<div id="txt" style="font-family: serif; font-size: 30pt; font-weight: bold; color: red;">00:00:00:00</div>
<div id="cal" style="font-family: serif; font-size: 30pt; font-weight: bold; color: red;>"00/00/0000</div>
<div id="video">
<video id="duck-movie" height="240"> 
<source src="duck.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Video is unavailable
</video>
</div>

</center>
</body></html>
```

EDIT: If I move the "video" div above the "txt" and "cal" divs, the video plays and the clock runs fine.

Comment: this line `<div id="cal" style="font-family: serif; font-size: 30pt; font-weight: bold; color: red;>"00/00/0000</div>` have a typo change for it: `<div id="cal" style="font-family: serif; font-size: 30pt; font-weight: bold; color: red;">00/00/0000</div>`

Comment: Cool to hear that you can fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

You use a HTML 4.01 doctype for this, but the video tag isn't part of HTML 4.01.  Try replacing your current doctype with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: But I can still play the video with the tag - I just have to comment out the 'txt' and 'cal' divs.

Comment: Take note of the comment on your original post by Aguardientico who spoke about your typo that could be invalidating the rest of your html.  The right doctype declaration is important so the browser doesn't have to think why you've used a tag that doesn't exist.

Comment: +1 for correct explain of DOCTYPE...   but browser does not think :P

Comment: Ok, think = compute and render.  By using elements not within the doctype, you're likely to hit the browser's quirks modes at where it renders the content as best as it can.  Shush it's Friday :P